# xml remove all values

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I just want to remove all xml element value and keep the namespaces in the original file.  I found some code that can remove values, but it also removes namespaces.  How can I just remove xml values?

```
 private static XElement RemoveAllNamespaces(XElement xmlDocument)
    {
        if (!xmlDocument.HasElements)
        {
            XElement xElement = new XElement(xmlDocument.Name.LocalName);
            xElement.Value = String.Empty;

            foreach (XAttribute attribute in xmlDocument.Attributes())
               xElement.Add(attribute);

            return xElement;
        }
        return new XElement(xmlDocument.Name.LocalName, xmlDocument.Elements().Select(el => RemoveAllNamespaces(el)));
    }
```

Comment: Do you want to keep the elements as well?

Comment: yes I just want to remove the xml values in the original file

Comment: @user1354345: Can you give a sample of input and expected output?

Comment: you could check the element name `XElement.Name.LocalName.StartsWith('xmlns')`

Comment: also `LocalName` will strip namespaces from the elements.  You want to use `xElement.Name.ToString()` to preserve namespaces in the elements.

Comment: .Name.ToString() fixes namespaces at top but still code removes namespace prefixs in elements